# Why is the derivative of $\frac{\partial{Tr(AXB)}}{\partial{X}}$ for symmetric matrix X equal to the asymmetric result?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, symmetric-matrices

I'm a bit confused of the fact that an online matrix calculus calculator (https://www.matrixcalculus.org/matrixCalculus) gives the same result for the derivative w.r.t. a symmetric matrix $X$ and a matrix $X$ without symmetry:

$$\frac{\partial{Tr(A^{T}XB)}}{\partial{X}} = AB^{T}$$

For an unstructured matrix we would apply formula (101) in the matrix cookbook ([https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)). In 2.8.2 they say we need to apply the following rule for symmetric matrices:

$$
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{X}} = \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{X}} + {\bigg[\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{X}} \bigg]}^T - diag \bigg(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{X}}\bigg) \\
\implies AB^{T} + BA^{T} - diag(AB^{T})
$$

What do I miss here?

Comment: The question come down to this: what do you mean by "the derivative with respect to a symmetric matrix $X$"? In the matrix cookbook, this derivative is defined as the derivative of the matrix with respect to the "structure matrix".

Comment: Ah, ok, it is actually only a scalar w.r.t. to a symmetric matrix. Hence, the rule does only matter for matrix w.r.t. a matrix?!

Comment: That's not what I said. Both of these apply to the derivative of a scalar with respect to a matrix.

Comment: Ok, I messed up the definitions... That was my mistake :) Thank you!

Comment: I mean the same definition as they use in the matrix cookbook.

Comment: Reading [this excellent paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.06491.pdf) may lead you to abandon the concept of symmetric gradients.

Comment: Thank you, @greg, for your hint! The paper helped a lot :) So the true derivative would be $G_s = sym(G)$, i.e. $G_s = (G + G^T)/2$ right?

Comment: That's correct. Out of curiosity, what do you plan to do with $G_s$?

Comment: I'm trying to derive the derivative of a multiple-output regression problem in matrix notation w.r.t. a symmetrical weight matrix.